# Sql in camel servicemix using jdbc in localmachine

Tags: sql, jdbc, apache-servicemix

I am using camel in servicemix on my localmachine i want to connect to sql server so i have to install jdbc or i can use m2 of servicemix please Help can i use camel-sql-datasource-h2 for sql operation if yes then i tried change username and password of \blueprint.xml but its not giving proper result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to provide the corresponding JDBC driver in your ServiceMix installation. For example, if you use MySQL you have to install the JDBC driver in ServicMix:

```
osgi:install -s mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34
```

In your datasource, you have to provide the corresponding properties, for MySQL:

```
<bean id="mySqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" scope="singleton">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myveo" />
    <property name="username" value="xxx" />
    <property name="password" value="yyy" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="0" />
</bean>
```

And configure the sql component like this

```
<bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource" />
</bean>
```

You use it like in this enrich component

```
<enrich uri="sql:select * from MY_TABLE;" strategyRef="myAggregationStrategy" strategyMethodAllowNull="true" />
```

Comment: Blueprint.xml          <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/${h2_database}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${h2_username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${h2_password}"/>
    </bean>
  **************
When i try to make connection using dataSource.getConnection()

Not allowing please help

Comment: How do you provide the placeholder values ${h2_...} to your context? Where do you get the dataSource for `dataSource.getConnection()` from?

Please provide more of your code, otherwise it's not possible to find the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `jdbc:create` command. You should install the `jdbc` feature first and create the data source like this

```
jdbc:create -t MySQL -i --username xxx --password yyy -url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myveo mySqlDataSource
```

The `-i` parameter will install the driver automatically. You can find the driver condiguration in `deploy/datasource-mySqlDataSource.xml`

You can next reference the data source using

```
<reference id="demoDataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```